# Angular: Scroll and focus to first invalid control in nested form once form has been submitted

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to scroll and focus invalid control in form onsubmit.
If I am using single form element its working as expected but when I am using nested `form`  element not working.

please find the sample example here [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-xycjka?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

How to scroll to invalid control and focus in nested forms on submit rootform.

Comment: Hm in your stackblitz demo the scroll is working.

Comment: @MishaMashina on scroll focus on control not working

Comment: I've added lot of linebreaks between your input fields, to be sure that there must be some scrolling if the code works - and it does scroll and focuses on invalid field after clicking submit.

Comment: @MishaMashina can you please review one more time on stackblitz example first invalid control is ```Nested Nested input box field``` there is no cursor on submit...for example ```GetFocus``` can you look this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_text_focus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found a solution to your problem.

In your directive, inside the method `scrollToFirstInvalidControl` change the line:

`const firstInvalidControl: any = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.ng-invalid');`

with:

```
let firstInvalidControl: any;
    let all = document.getElementsByClassName('ng-invalid');
    for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
      if(all[i].tagName == 'INPUT'){
        firstInvalidControl = all[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

It will take all elements that have a `ng-invalid` class, but will check only those that have a `tagName` as `INPUT` - since your validation is for input fields, not whole forms as such (your original code caught first invalid form, but that wasn't the form that had an input that you wanted to scroll to).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In actual am looking for the some dynamic solution where input type anything and based on current ```this.el.nativeElement``` where directive is applied because i have multiple forms ngsubmit in same window.

Comment: As long as you're using `input` tag, this will work dynamically.